# adding pointers to dynamic pointer array in a loop in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a structure that represents a row in a table:

```
typedef struct {
    char *a;
    char *b;
} row;
```

and I have a function that initializes that row based on db data and returns a pointer to it

```
row* get_row(dbrow d) {
    row *r = malloc(sizeof(row));
    r->a = malloc(5);
    strcpy(r->a, d.a);
    r->b = malloc(5);
    strcpy(r->b, d.b);
    return r;
}
```

and finally, I have a function that has an `row **rows` as a parameter:

```
void get_rows(row **rows) {
    ...
    rows = malloc(rowNumber * sizeof(row*));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++) {
        rows[i] = get_row(dbrow);
    }
}
```

get_row works as expected and returns a pointer to valid row struct, but gdb shows that rows[0] (and all the others) never gets a new value, that is, it always points to the same address, almost as if the `rows[i] = get_row(dbrow)` line doesn't exist.

Comment: where does `rowNumber` come from? could you maybe post your whole code?

Comment: rowNumber is initialized to 1. surrounding code deals with database access and is kinda messy, it works, and it does really have an impact on the shown code. everything up to pointer assignment works as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...gdb shows that rows[0] (and all the others) never gets a new value...

I'm assuming here that you are looking at the return value of your `get_rows` function, not at the value of its local variable `rows`.  Here is the problem:

```
rows = malloc(rowNumber * sizeof(row*));
```

You are assigning a new value to a *copy* of the original pointer that the function received, not the original.  This change will not be visible outside the function.

If you need to assign a new value to the argument then you will need to add another level of indirection.  Remember; ***everything*** in C is passed by value.  So, your function should take a `row***` as its argument:

```
void get_rows(row ***rows) {
    if(!rows) {
        signal_some_error();
        return;
    }
    ...
    *rows = malloc(rowNumber * sizeof(row*));
    ...
}
```

---

Also, as user1700513 pointed out, you are assigning a `row*` to a row.  That can't be your actual code as it would result in a compiler error.

Comment: the issue manifests before get_rows returns, straight after assignment line. it should still work if only in the scope, right?

Comment: So, what I mentioned above is still an error that needs to be fixed, otherwise your function is useless.  If there is a problem *inside* the function as well then you haven't posted all of the code that is relevant.  `get_row` returns a `malloc`d pointer every time, so unless you're stomping on memory somewhere your question is missing something.  `malloc` cannot possibly return the same address twice in a row without a delete in between.  Are `d.a` and `d.b` properly terminated C strings?  Is `5` bytes large enough to hold them?  How are you declaring `rows` before passing it to the function?

Comment: @cbaby: ...What is is the value of `rowNumber`?  There is information missing here, we need more code.

Comment: Found it: get_rows need to get a reference to row **rows, I was passing pointer "by value" as you pointed out.

Comment: @cbaby: ... :D.  Glad you got it solved.  Just to be pedantic; there is no such things as pass by reference in C.  Everything is passed by value, so when you need to assign a new value to an argument you must add an additional level of indirection.

Answer (score 3):

change `row r = malloc(sizeof(row));` to `row* r = malloc(sizeof(row));`. I am wondering why you didn't get a compiler warning for this.

Comment: It should be an error as there is no implicit conversion from `void*` to `row`.  I bet that was a typo and the real code declares a pointer.

Comment: @cbaby: Best to just copy the code verbatim.  Did you try my suggestion?